# example how to use tmpfs to store directories in memory by java

Tags: java, directory, tmpfs

i want to create a directory in the memory and after a few days of                                                             googling i found that using tmpfs is one of ways to do that, please if any one     knows how to create directories using tmpfs and java.
    here's what i'm using to create directory in the system.

```
File currentFolder = new File( "path" );
    File workingFolder = new File( currentFolder, "serialized" );
    if ( !workingFolder.exists() ) {
        workingFolder.mkdir();
    }
    System.out.println( workingFolder.getAbsolutePath() );
```

Comment: tmpfs (linux) is a file system so you need to mount a tmpfs partition with system command. After you will be able to create a directory within.

Comment: yes you're right, do you know an way to store directories in the memory??

Comment: If you use linux tmpfs is a good way, usually /tmp is mount over tmpfs filesysteme. On windows you need a tool like RAMDisk to create a directory in ram.

Comment: thanks for the these answers but how matter the OS used, what i want exactly is to create this folder in the memory and this this folder must be deleted automatiquelly